# Tricking WURFL mobile detection

Tags: wurfl

I'm trying to test the mobile version of a webpage on my desktop. It uses WURFL for mobile detection, which I thought could be tricked by changing my user agent.

This has no impact on what page is displayed to me..

Any ideas how I can trick the page into showing me the mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the caching strategy that the website is using, you may need to clear your cookies in order to test both versions of the site. Spoofing your User Agent is the correct method in order to "trick" the website into serving the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Elliot said, the fact that the mobile version of your page is not shown may depend on how you implemented the routing of your website, so check that, after the device has been detected, the request is properly forwarded to the mobile version.